# list' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python

I am new to python and was trying to sort the dates in a list. Below is the code that I wrote and getting
following error on the below line

`#### date_object = datetime_object.date()  ## list' object has no attribute 'date'`

```
from datetime import datetime,date
lst_dates = ['01 Apr 2017', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Dec 2018', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Jan 2017', '01 Jan 2018']
datetime_object = sorted(lst_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y'))
date_object = datetime_object.date()
print(date_object)
```

Please assist in helping me understand what the issues is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you code is on line #3 when you are writing

```
datetime_object = sorted(lst_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y'))
```

**sorted** function in Python returns a new python **list** object. If you want to check then run

```
type(datetime_object)
```

So in order to achieve what you want here you need to iterate over that list. Your final code would be something like this

```
from datetime import datetime,date
lst_dates = ['01 Apr 2017', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Dec 2018', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Jan 2017', '01 Jan 2018']
datetime_obj_list = sorted(lst_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y'))

for datetime_object in datetime_obj_list:
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_object, "%d %b %Y")
    print(datetime_object.date())
```

**UPDATE**:
Here's a working sample of the code https://ideone.com/YRDQR7

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. It would be great if you can upvote also.

Comment: It gave me the following error. Please advise                                                                                                                           date_object = datetime_object.date()                                              
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: Kindly check it now.

Answer (score 2):

## Python don't have the list.date() function, with below code list of dates can be sorted.

```
from datetime import datetime
lst_dates = ['01 Apr 2017', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Dec 2018', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Jan 2017', '01 Jan 2018']
lst_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y"))
print(lst_dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on 4th line

it should be  `date_object = datetime.date()`

Comment: This will get the current date, not the date of the datetime object, which is what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
from datetime import datetime,date
lst_dates = ['01 Apr 2017', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Dec 2018', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Jan 2017', '01 Jan 2018']
datetime_object = sorted(lst_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y'))
#date_object = datetime_object.date()  # <<-- remove this line
print(datetime_object)
```

testing:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,date
>>> lst_dates = ['01 Apr 2017', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Dec 2018', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Jan 2017', '01 Jan 2018']
>>> datetime_object = sorted(lst_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y'))
>>> print(datetime_object)
['01 Jan 2017', '01 Feb 2017', '01 Apr 2017', '01 Aug 2017', '01 Dec 2017', '01 Jan 2018', '01 Feb 2018', '01 Apr 2018', '01 Aug 2018', '01 Dec 2018']
>>>
```